# Reparing a corrupt Time Machine backup on a Time Capsule won't work

Tags: macos, time-machine, time-capsule, repair

I tried to follow these instructions:

http://www.garth.org/archives/2011,08,27,169,fix-time-machine-sparsebundle-nas-based-backup-errors.html

But after typing in the hdiutil command I only get one partition:

```
bash-3.2# hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/Data/Ulfs\ iMac.sparsebundle/
/dev/disk1
```

So all the steps after this command are not available to me.

Afterwards I tried to mount the sparse bundle using the disk utility. After several hours the image appeared in the sidebar of my disk utility. There I tried to execute the repair volume function, which took about two hours. But still I'm not able to mount the image. I tried all this from two different Macs.

Is there anything left I could do to save my backup history?